# Flaw in the method for studying variation of functions

Tags: functions

I have the following equation:

$h(x) = (5-2x)^2$

Which can be rewritten as g of f of x if:

$g(x) = x^2 ; f(x) = 5 - 2x$

Now if I draw out the variations of the two functions and combine them, I get the opposite of what I should, I am aware that the source of the problem is that $f(x)$ could equally be $2x - 5$, but is there a mathematical reason for which this doesn't work?

Comment: What do you get when you combine them? Without knowing exactly what you've done, it's difficult to say where you're going wrong.

Comment: g of f of x means start with x, do f to it to get $5-2x$ and then do g to that to get $(5-2x)^2$. You work your way backwards from x, not left to right from g.